# MICROSOFT SQL server and windows azure with Mac OS X and Cocoa

Tags: sql, ios, macos, cocoa, odbc

So I am currently doing some research for creating iPhone and Mac applications for my company and perhaphs other small businesses. I have found god knows loads and loads of books on cocoa and iOS development, but on the side of SQL server things get a little more shady. I have seen all kinds of products online who claim to be the best SQL driver and to be the simplest and performance enhanced way of adding a relational database to your cocoa app. I have currently been and still create desktop applications under windows and we extensively use our databases for almost all applications and reports we build. We have iPads and iPhone all around our company and I could really bring some innovative apps to our table if we could have some of our workflows or reports on the iPhone or iPad. I cannot seem to find a viable SQL driver like using visual studio under widows. Is there a obvious solution that I have missed or do developers just not deal with enterprise projects with relational databases? We as a company have the capabilities to create what ever web or server needed to get such a project underway but before I do I want to make sure I can work with our existing database as I could with visual studio, any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is one of reasons why is there sooo little enterprise-class software on Macs... As a first candidate I would consider FreeTDS to access SQL Servers. It has headers and libraries that can be linked in XCode as far as I know.

Comment: What if I use windows azure or a cloud based SQL database, create a WCF service to run on the cloud and then implement an http request from cocoa to my wcf service. The wcf service could run the SQL and return the results as nothing more than XML. I think cocoa has a really good method of parsing XML..any thoughts or reasons why not to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your post and comments, you do have great design in your mind. For having an application to compatible with any mobile device, the best application design would be to have your application running on as cloud service connected to specific cloud DB while application is talking to it over any exposed interface.

With Windows Azure your application can run as Cloud Service while using SQL database. In your cloud service you can have WCF endpoint exposed which can serve connection to your SQL Database and provide specific data you are looking for. This way your cloud application will be able to serve any mobile device as long as you can make connection to secure WCF endpoint and get back the data.  In WCF you not only get XML data, you can pass much more complex results and process in the device as if needed.

Comment: My idea was to have a WCF service running on windows azure to act as the exposed portion to the SQL database. Then the application would send as a string or XML the sql statment to be ran, The WCF service would execute that SQL statment and then return the result set as XML back to the cocoa application.
Would my idea be a good implementation?